# Refinish (reporcelain) a toilet?

Tags: bathroom, toilet, remodeling

We have a Kohler circa 1989 wall mount toilet; i.e., the seat and tank are both on an outside wall. It's also avocado green.

Is it possible to have the toilet refinished in another color? Pros? Cons?

Comment: Pros: You can spend more than the toilet's worth to have a pretty, old toilet. Wait, that's a con. Cons: see pros.

Comment: Can't be reasonably done. Get a new one.

Comment: As I understand it, current wall mounts all have the tank inside the wall. That would require the expense of reconfiguring the wall. Also, does "reasonably done" refer to just $$ or to the toilet itself?

Comment: http://www.rustoleum.com/product-catalog/consumer-brands/specialty/tub-and-tile-refreshing-kit

We carried this product in the paint department when I worked at the orange box store.

Comment: You may want to check on local companies specializing in tub refinishing. While "Bathfitters" manufactures a liner to fit over your tub other companies apply a coating to the existing surface. If they can do a tub I don't see why they can't do a toilet.